# Why the list is covering whole screen?

Tags: react-native

Why my FlatList is until bottom? that list suppose that just cover 100px of height at the top, the list is covering whole screen, how can i solve that?

```
const DATA = [
    {
        id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
        title: 'First Item',
    },
    {
        id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
        title: 'Second Item',
    },
    {
        id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
        title: 'Third Item',
    },
]

const LeftContent = props => <Avatar.Icon {...props} icon="folder" />

const Item = ({ title }) => (
    <Card style={{
        height: 70
    }}>
        <Card.Title title="Card Title" subtitle="Card Subtitle" left={LeftContent} />

    </Card>
)

const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item title={item.title} />
)

return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
    }}>

        <FlatList

            horizontal
            data={DATA}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />


        <FAB
            icon="plus"
            style={styles.fab}
            onPress={() => console.log('Pressed')}
        />


    </SafeAreaView>
)
```

i need these styles for my button at the bottom, i knew that those styles it generating the wrong. there is a way to solve it?

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    fab: {
        position: 'absolute',
        margin: 16,
        right: 25,
        bottom: 100,
    },
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can check this snack:

https://snack.expo.dev/5mRnaZm7T

[image]

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet ,SafeAreaView,FlatList } from 'react-native';


// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';

export default function App() {
 const DATA = [
    {
        id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
        title: 'First Item',
    },
    {
        id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
        title: 'Second Item',
    },
    {
        id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
        title: 'Third Item',
    },
]

// const LeftContent = props => <Avatar.Icon {...props} icon="folder" />

const Item = ({ title }) => (
    <Card style={{
        height: 70
    }}>
        <Card.Title title="Card Title" subtitle="Card Subtitle" />

    </Card>
)

const renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <Item title={item.title} />
)

return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{
        flex: 1,
 
    }}>

        <FlatList
            style={{backgroundColor:'red',flexGrow:0,height:100}}
            horizontal
            data={DATA}
            renderItem={renderItem}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id}
        />


       


    </SafeAreaView>
)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping FlatList in a **View** Tag and then apply 100px height to that view.

**OR**

Add the following styling to flatlist

```
flatList: {
 height: 100,
 flexGrow: 0
}
```